# Talend-Validating and transforming coordinates from a text file

Tags: coordinates, transformation, talend

Hello: I have an issue with a set of data and I would like to know if its possible to fix this using **Talend**.
I have a data set with coordinates. **Took me  a while to realize that the coordinates are not only switched (**X** for *Y* and **Y** for *X*) but also they **come in two different projections**.
My data looks like:

```
Id│    X         │ Y
1│     215778.54 │ 617648.14
2│     219191.29 │ 655609.72
3│     173675.30 │ 622692.27
4│     1187393.25│ 2688086.83
5│     1131589.73│ 2630282.11
6│     115808.64 │ 647745.84
7│     523240.73 │ 154652.36
8│     158439.43 │ 508216.93
9│     2758248.73│ 1174926.26
10│    265761.71 │ 750733.22
```

*I found out the max and min range that **x** and **y** have according to the projection:*

```
**Projection 1:**

* xmin = 480'000  
* xmax = 840'000
* ymin =   60'000    
* ymax = 300'000

**Projection 2:**

* xmin = 2'480'000
* xmax = 2'840'000
* ymin = 1'060'000
* ymax = 1'300'000
```

Given the data now my questions:

**1)** I was thinking to use these ranges as limits or something to place the coordinates correctly. there my question:  how can i make the changes in variables in order that they get organized in the were they belong **x to its correspondent x  and y to its correspondent y**  *(should look like this):*

```
**Id│   XPr1│   YLPr1│  XPr2│   YPr2**
1│  617648.14│  215778.54│  2617648.49│ 1215778.73│
2│  655609.72│  219191.29│  2655610.47│ 1219191.28│
3│  622692.27│  173675.30│  2622692.32│ 1173675.09│
```

**2)** Once the coordinates were placed in their correspondent way, I would like to make the transformation to geographical **(lat/long) format decimal degrees.**
*(should look like this):*

```
**Id│   XPr1│   YLPr1│  XPr2│ YPr2│ XGeo│   YGeo│**
1│  617648.14│  215778.54│  2617648.49│ 1215778.73│ 7.67│   47.09│
2│  655609.72│  219191.29│  2655610.47│ 1219191.28│ 8.17│   47.12│
3│  622692.27│  173675.30│  2622692.32│ 1173675.09│ 7.74│   46.71│
```

Thanks for reading and double thanks for answering :)

Comment: For those of us who don't understand how geographical data work, could you please explain how you're getting XPr2 and YPr2 in your first question ? And for you 2nd question, how are you getting XGeo and YGeo ?

Comment: Sorry, my bet.  I used ArcGis for doing that. 1) I got x1 and y1. 2) Since I din't have any clue of which kind of coordinates were, _(I knew that they must be deployed in Swiss)_  I used software ArcGis to project them and verify that they were deploying in that country.  3) Then it was when realize about the mix between coordinates and projections. 4) Once detecting the coordinate system  I split them into projection 1 and projection 2 (xpr1/ypr1 and xpr2/ypr2). Whenever I have the lack of one projection, I transformed into another and visc using the same software. 5) ...

Comment: ..5) once I got an uniform pair of coordinates, _no matter if it was projection 1 or 2_ , I transformed into lat/long using the same sofware.  And that's how i Got the final table.    The thing is that I need to implement this procedure into a "cleaning process" that is done with Talend.  That's why I am asking. But if someone also knows an options using mysql, would be welcome as well. (i think there is no options for coordinate transformations in mysql...or?)

Comment: So you transformed them using ArcGis, but do you know what rules are applied to X and Y coordinates in order to get XPr2 and YPr2 (and XGeo, YGeo), so that we can apply those transformations in Talend ?

Comment: for making transformations in projections you **always** have to know in which system they are.  Once you know you can transform them in any other wished system.  ArcGis has a special tool to do this without bothering about knowing the formula applied. Since I am new in Talend and I have to develop a "production line" and automatize this procedure. I just wanted to know whether in Talend was possible this level of transformations and cleaning messy coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a plugin for Talend that can do this sort of stuff. https://www.talend.com/blog/2017/08/07/how-to-seamlessly-include-geospatial-data-and-operations-into-your-data-integration-process/

Comment: Thanks Francis, I will try with what you suggested. I will keep you posted!  :)